# Cleanup task for npm-snapshots repository on Nexus

Tags: npm, nexus

My requirement is to remove packages older than 30 days from npm snapshot repository on nexus.
Nexus provides clean-up task for maven packages and that I have am using.

Maven Task:
[image]

Looking for similar functionality for npm packages.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: In NXRM3.14 we released the described format generic cleanup solution as described [here](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Cleanup+Policies).  This should cover the case described here.  There may be other cases needed (for example, number retained as shown in the screenshot), in which case feel free to look for and file a JIRA ticket if you do not see the feature request.

Currently there is no such task in NXRM3.
We are actively working on a general (non-Maven specific) cleanup solution.  There are tickets in the tracking system, see here as an example: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-12706.
Your use case should be covered by our design but if you have any specific needs, feel free to comment there or on [our user list](https://groups.google.com/a/glists.sonatype.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/nexus-users).